# java - field won't update

Tags: java

The balance field won't update when `AddBirthdayBonus` is called. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class class
{
    private float balance;
    private float bob;


    public class(float amount, float bob)
    {
                    balance = amount;
                }
    birthdate = birthday;
    }


    public void AddBirthdayBonus(float todayDate)
    {
      if (todayDate == bob)
      {
     balance += 5;
     }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it's not updating? Where are you using it that it's not showing up correctly?

Comment: Is this really Java? I'm pretty sure this won't even compile. How about supplying a code sample that gets past the compiler first.

Comment: Can you debug and test that todayDate and bob are the same?  Could be a rounding bug...

Comment: That code doesn't even compile

Comment: It's not java, but what he thought would make a good example.  Class is a keyword, so you can't name a class "class".

Answer (score 2):

Something like this has more chances to work:

```
public class MyClass{
    private float balance;
    private float bob;


    public MyClass(float balance, float bob)
    {
                    this.balance = balance;
                    this.bob = bob;
    }


    public void AddBirthdayBonus(float todayDate)
    {
      if (todayDate == bob){
        balance += 5;
      }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bob has no value here so you can't compare it with another variable, you should assign a value to it to be able to compare it with another variable